# Swipeable UINavigationController with static bar buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm interested in recreating an interface almost identical to Twitter's timelines interface. In this interface, you can swipe through what I assume is view controllers within a navigation controller. However I've noticed that the bar button items remain static while the navigation title transitions with the view controllers. Is this actually a collection view controller with container view controllers?

How can this be accomplished? (image below)

[image]

Comment: I think it's a page view controller within a navigation controller. and use a animation to do the slide out and slide in for the navigation bar title.

Comment: @XuYin you nailed it on the head. However there's one thing that's missing: how to add a uipagecontrol within a navigation bar.

Comment: I think there are a couple of different ways to achieve that, in my app, i used a 3rd part library called "Swipe view", which works pretty good for me. it's like a page view controller, but you can embed it into any view controller you want, in your case, navigation controller. here is the github link: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

Comment: @XuYin what's different about that from UIPageViewController?

Comment: Conceptually, The biggest difference is UIPageViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, but that one is UIView. But functionally, i don't see too much difference.